# When to write two-lettered words with capital?

Tags: capitalization

Let's say I have a few titles here:

> Fire *in* Our Hands
>   Who *am* I
>   Land of Dreams

Do I write the *italic* words with capitals like the other words, 
or is it properly written the way it is?

Comment: Usually, in titles, prepositions are not capitalized, so you have done it exactly correctly.

Comment: "am" should certainly be capitalized.

Comment: "am" is not important enough to warrant capitalization, so it's fine the way it is in a _title_ (but not an outright error to capitalize it). You would write _Let's go to Europe_ as a travel guide title, not _Let's Go to Europe_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there are many variations in rules regarding capitalization of titles. Depending on which style guide you follow, it may be that all words are capitalized, or that certain words are lowercase. Words often lowercase include articles, prepositions (or prepositions under a certain length - "to" and "in" but not "through") and short words that are part of the verb "to be". Consistency is important, but so is clarity - a style guide is supposed to help you, not enslave you. It provides guidelines that work in most cases, but there are always exceptions.

So, if the emphasis of a word in the title is important enough to italicize, my inclination would be to capitalize it, regardless of style guide rules. I might even write the whole word in uppercase - *Fire IN Our Hands, Who AM I?*